# (intermediate value).get is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to integrate an API with my angular project which displays the internet speed of my connection. this is an api which is provided by fast.com - https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-speedtest-api I am trying to follow just as how it is being mentioned in the doc of NPM package. The error that I am receiving is

```
app.component.ts:18 (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).get is not a function
```

As per what i understood on google is it must be a syntax error but i dont find any errors in my typescript file. below is my typescript code

```
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');
const Timer = require('./Timer');
const ApiError = require('./ApiError');

    const FastSpeedtest = require("fast-speedtest-api");
     
    let speedtest = new FastSpeedtest({
        token: "YXNkZmFTOKENoYXNkZmhrYWxm", // required
        verbose: false, // default: false
        timeout: 10000, // default: 5000
        https: true, // default: true
        urlCount: 5, // default: 5
        bufferSize: 8, // default: 8
        unit: FastSpeedtest.UNITS.Mbps // default: Bps
    });
     
    speedtest.getSpeed().then((s :any) => {
        console.log(`Speed: ${s} Mbps`);
    }).catch((e :any) => {
        console.error(e.message);
    });
```

just in case, i have also checked the async method that was there from the npm package itself. I do not find an error in there as well.

```
/**
 * Get data from the specified URL
 *
 * @async
 * @param {string} url The URL to download from
 * @return {Promise} The request and response from the URL
 */
async get(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = (this.https ? https : http).get(url, (response) => {
            if (response.headers['content-type'].includes('json')) {
                response.setEncoding('utf8');
                let rawData = '';
                response.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    rawData += chunk;
                });
                response.on('end', () => {
                    const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
                    response.data = parsedData;
                    resolve({
                        response,
                        request
                    });
                });
            } else {
                resolve({
                    response,
                    request
                });
            }
        }).on('error', (e) => {
            reject(e);
        });
    });
}
```

what might be the issue?

Comment: You're trying to import this in you angular app or your Backend ??

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler straightly in the Angular App. backend is not involved yet!

Comment: That's a Backend package, not compatible with an angular app.

Comment: there is no way to do a speed test in Angular then?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler can you post it as an answer, i can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fast-speedtest-api` is meant to be used on nodejs not an angular app !

Comment: Angular runs on Node.

Comment: @paddotk It's build with node, but runs in the browser.

Comment: Yes, so what's your point?

Comment: I'm answering his question. The point is `fast-speedtest-api` won't run in the browser as he would have expected.

Comment: The package docs don't make any mention of it only working in a Node backend, so I don't see why it wouldn't work like that.

Comment: @paddotk the package doesnt mention any key points. its poorly been done. I have tried it on Node, it worked. created a websocket and passed it. worked like charm.

Comment: So because it worked for you, you assume that that is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:
`(this.https ? https : http).get(...)`

You try to resolve what to call the `get` on, but with wrong scoping. `this.https != https`. Since the package `https` is an import, it won't be on the `this` scope.
I do wonder however, what the point of this is. Is using http a fallback for when the https package can't be found? What is it what you're trying to check here?

As a sidenote, debugging (and reading the code, for that matter) would be easier if you do something like

```
const resolver = https ? https : http;
resolver.get(...)
```